# getadaptersinfo produce the first adapter information in x64 configuration

Tags: windows, api, intel-fortran

I use the getadaptersinfo method in a fortran project, trying to find the mac address of all the adapters on a computer. The program works fine in win32 mode, giving a list of adapters information on the computer. But it does not work properly if x64 configuration is selected. In that case, the program can be compiled, but when it is executed, only the first adapter information will be given.
The code is as follows:

```
PROGRAM MAC
USE ifwinty
IMPLICIT NONE
!
INTEGER, PARAMETER :: MAX_ADAPTER_DESCRIPTION_LENGTH = 128 !// arb.
INTEGER, PARAMETER :: MAX_ADAPTER_NAME_LENGTH        = 256 !// arb.
INTEGER, PARAMETER :: MAX_ADAPTER_ADDRESS_LENGTH     =   8 !// arb.
!
TYPE :: IP_ADDRESS_STRING
  CHARACTER (4) :: String(4)
END TYPE
TYPE :: IP_MASK_STRING
  CHARACTER (4) :: String(4)
END TYPE
!
TYPE :: t_IP_ADDR_STRING 
 INTEGER (LPLONG) :: pNext
 TYPE (IP_ADDRESS_STRING) :: IpAddress
 TYPE (IP_MASK_STRING) :: IpMask
 INTEGER (DWORD)      :: Context
END TYPE
!
TYPE :: t_IP_ADAPTER_INFO
 INTEGER (LPLONG) :: pNext 
 INTEGER (DWORD) :: ComboIndex
 CHARACTER (LEN = MAX_ADAPTER_NAME_LENGTH + 4) :: AdapterName
 CHARACTER (LEN = MAX_ADAPTER_DESCRIPTION_LENGTH + 4) :: Description
 INTEGER (UINT) :: AddressLength
 INTEGER (BYTE) :: Address(MAX_ADAPTER_ADDRESS_LENGTH)
 INTEGER (DWORD) :: Index
 INTEGER (ULONG) :: iType
 INTEGER (ULONG) :: DhcpEnabled
 INTEGER (LPLONG) :: pCurrentIpAddress 
 TYPE (t_IP_ADDR_STRING) :: IpAddressList
 TYPE (t_IP_ADDR_STRING) :: GatewayList
 TYPE (t_IP_ADDR_STRING) :: DhcpServer
 INTEGER (BOOL) :: HaveWins
 TYPE (t_IP_ADDR_STRING) :: PrimaryWinsServer
 TYPE (t_IP_ADDR_STRING) :: SecondaryWinsServer
 INTEGER (ULONG) :: LeaseObtained
 INTEGER (ULONG) :: LeaseExpires;
END TYPE 
!
INTERFACE
 INTEGER (BOOL) FUNCTION GetAdaptersInfo(arg1, arg2)
 USE ifwinty
 !DEC$ ATTRIBUTES DEFAULT, STDCALL, DECORATE, ALIAS:'GetAdaptersInfo' :: GetAdaptersInfo
 INTEGER (LPLONG) :: arg1
 INTEGER (LPLONG) :: arg2
 END FUNCTION
END INTERFACE
!
TYPE (t_IP_ADAPTER_INFO) :: AdapterInfo(16)
CHARACTER(LEN=17)::MACAddr(16)
CHARACTER(LEN=500) :: str1,str2
TYPE (t_IP_ADDR_STRING) :: CurrentIpAddress
INTEGER (DWORD) :: dwRetVal 
INTEGER (BOOL) :: iret
INTEGER :: i,j,m,k
LOGICAL::search4Next
CHARACTER(Len=500)::info_out(50) 



dwRetVal = sizeof(AdapterInfo)
!dwRetVal=10240
PRINT*,dwRetVal
!PRINT*,AdapterInfo
iret = GetAdaptersInfo(LOC(AdapterInfo), LOC(dwRetVal))
IF (iret /= 0) STOP 'Error'
DO i = 1, 16
! PRINT *, AdapterInfo(1)%pNext
! PRINT *, AdapterInfo(1)%ComboIndex
! PRINT *, AdapterInfo(1)%AddressLength
 PRINT *, AdapterInfo(i)%Description(1:INDEX(AdapterInfo(i)%Description(1:128), CHAR(0)))
 PRINT *, AdapterInfo(i)%ITYPE
 PRINT '(5(Z2.2,"-"), Z2.2)', AdapterInfo(i)%Address(1:AdapterInfo(i)%AddressLength)
 write(MACAddr(i),'(5(Z2.2,"-"), Z2.2)') AdapterInfo(i)%Address(1:AdapterInfo(i)%AddressLength)
 MACAddr(i)=TRIM(MACAddr(i))
     

 
 IF (AdapterInfo(i)%pNext == NULL) THEN
    EXIT
    read(*,*)
 ENDIF
END DO
read(*,*)
STOP


  
    
   END PROGRAM MAC
```

Does anyone can help to explain why is that?

Comment: Please show your code, see [mre].

Comment: You will have much more luck with these details in the official forum https://community.intel.com/t5/Intel-Fortran-Compiler/bd-p/fortran-compiler